# How to react to size changes caused by autolayout constraint on a UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have a custom UIView with a certain appearance. I want it so if the width of the UIView changes due to code setting its autolayout width constraint, I want to react to the change by changing the appearance accordingly - one example of this would be to set the corner radius.

How can my custom UIView react to size changes caused by autolayout constraint on a UIView?

Comment: Can you update them in [layoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews)?

Answer (score 4):

Override `layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self updateCornerRadius];
}
```

Comment: That was easy. Is this the only method in UIView that got triggered when layout constraint is applied to it?

Comment: I believe auto layout sends `setCenter:` and `setBounds:` to the view to set its position and size, so you could override those, but I'd recommend just overriding `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Well, there's also [`drawRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect:) which may get sent.  But I too recommend sticking to layoutSubviews.